Unable to Retrieve Valid Access Token Using fetchAuthSession Function
I'm encountering an issue with the fetchAuthSession function from ifetchAuthSession. Here's the problem:
When I log in using Postman with the following API: https://myDomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token, I receive a valid access token. I can successfully use this token to make authorized API calls to the following endpoint:

https://my/dev/transactions/totals?fund_id=78773d35-4272-4891-989d-ffae9dac59d4&limit=10

However, when attempting to retrieve the token using the fetchAuthSession function, I'm receiving a 401 Unauthorized error. I'm not sure why this is happening.
Note that if i copy the access token from the oauth2/token on postman -> its working perfectly without issues.
Here's an example of the code I'm using:
async function currentSession() {
 try {
const { accessToken } = (await fetchAuthSession()).tokens ?? {};
return accessToken; // Return the accessToken
} catch (err) {
console.log(err);
  }
}

export const fetchTotalTransactions = async () => {
try {
 const accessToken = await currentSession(); 
 if (!accessToken) {
  throw new Error("Access token not found");
  }
  console.log("ccccc", accessToken.payload);
   const response = await fetch(
  "https://v7rz2vn2tl.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/transactions/totals? 
   fund_id=78773d35-4272-4891-989d-ffae9dac59d4&limit=10",
    {
    method: "GET",
    mode: "no-cors",
    headers: {
      "x-access-token": `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
  }
 );

if (!response.ok) {
  throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
}

 return response.json();
} catch (error) {
 console.error(error);
 throw error; // Re-throw the error to be handled by the caller
  }
};


I'm not sure why the access token obtained from fetchAuthSession is resulting in a 401 error, while the token obtained from Postman works fine. Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
What i tried:

access token
id token
Access token from the postman oauth2/token -> working ( but i need it to be working from fetchAuthSession)

